# How do editors of mathematical journals know that a submited paper is original, that is unpublished?

Tags: soft-question, publishing

I wondered many times how the editors of mathematical journals know that the content of a paper or article that was submited by an author is original, this is, that the main content of such calculations and reasonings is unpublished.

> **Question.** How do editors of mathematical journals know that a submited paper is original, that is unpublished? **Many thanks.**

I would like to know it as curiosity, because I imagine that professors working in mathematical journals are experts in a field of mathematics. Then a day they receive a writing, a paper or a remark, with perhaps several results, and they have to evaluate if this was not published or known previously. 
Additionally I imagine that these professors or editors have tools to search information for this purpose, and maybe they have contact with other colleagues who have historical memory about what results, and of what kind, have been published. Am I wrong in these believes? How do they know and they note the originality of such mathematical content?

Comment: This is why there is a peer review. But, there are many mistakes. I have been the victim of plagiarism several times.

Comment: Point of detail, but wouldn't that be better suited to [academia.SE](https://academia.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici How is plagiarism relevant here?

Comment: I'm sorry that you tell me. I am asking as curiosity because I think even that it must be complicated task. Many thanks for you attention and good day  @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: For each field, there are some so-called "state-of-art" papers referencing all the open-problems and the known theorems. When those are made correctly, they are well-known by everyone in the field and it is enough to check in it if the treated problem is referenced and solved. The author is supposed to reference it in his paper.

Comment: @reuns Could you point to such a paper? I have never seen such.

Comment: Many thanks @ClementC.

Comment: Feel free to add an asnwer @reuns

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft In number theory, see http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Unsolved%20Problems%20In%20Number%20Theory%202%20Ed%20-%20R%20K%20Guy.pdf or https://books.google.fr/books/about/Handbook_of_Number_Theory_II.html?id=B2WZkvmFKk8C&redir_esc=y or https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01220304/document

Comment: @reuns The last one is fairly new, but only considers one (very well-known) problem. The other two are already really old and claiming something to be open based on such an old reference seems unlikely to be taken seriously. Further, most research papers in number theory will not be related to anything even remotely close to the problems mentioned in those sources.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So what do you mean ? Number theory exists since 500 years so it is rather special. Anyway at least 1/4 of the PhD, articles and books are of the category "state of art". Without those, it would be hard to learn about a new field, and also most researchers would be fired (because finding new ideas is hard). See also thisone http://math.hawaii.edu/home/theses/MA_2014_Hallum.pdf

Comment: @reuns There is nothing special about number theory in this context. Most problems that could be formulated that long ago will either be completely uninteresting or trivial today (a few will be interesting and still impossible to make any headway on, but those are very few). While PhD thesis will often contain some amount of summary of the state of the art, that will not be their main contribution. And I highly doubt that 1/4 of the research papers are reviews of the state of the art (and a quick glance in the category on arXiv seems to confirm that).

Comment: @reuns I am not sure what that link was supposed to show. It is a master's thesis.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That's my experience in signal processing and machine learning, and in maths I read almost only some state-of-art books, thesis, articles (because those are in general much easier to understand)

Comment: @reuns But that does not in any way imply any of the previous things you claimed.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It is a master thesis where the teachers clearly helped him and really wanted a state of art about this topic. It seems you don't claim anything.

Comment: @reuns What I claim is that you are wrong in your claim that the way people check if some result is new is to consult some "state of the art" paper or book. People check this by looking through the relevant literature (all of it, not just the review-style papers) on a combination of arXiv and MathSciNet, using that they already have a lot of expertise in the specific type of problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When submitting a paper for publication, it is not only the editor who looks at it. The editor will (usually) take a first look to determine if the paper looks to be suitable for the journal. If they see that the main results are already well-known this will likely make them reject the paper (especially if the authors have not made any remark on this themselves).

If this is not the case and the paper generally looks fine (this also includes the results actually seeming to be interesting), then the paper will be sent to one or two experts in the field for review. These will (hopefully) take a much closer look at the paper and determine if they think it is suitable for the journal. Once again, this will include trying to determine whether the results are actually new, which is why it is important for the editor to choose reviewers who really are experts, as otherwise they will not be familiar enough with the field to determine this.

Finally, the reviewers will make a recommendation to the editor based on their reading, and using the editor will make a final decision on whether to accept the paper, possibly contingent on certain improvements.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. In next hours I should be choose an answer.

Comment: @user243301 There is no rush with that. Give it however long and see if more answers appear that might be better.

Comment: See https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-0-387-26677-0 for a recent and purely state-of-start work.

Comment: @reuns As far as I can tell that book is from 2004 (unless it doesn't indicate the latest edition there). And I am not sure what you claim that book does. If a problem is claimed as unsolved in that, how will that guarantee that it was not solved since? What about problems not mentioned in that book?

Comment: The idea is that there are a lot of researchers and students working on state-of-art in a particular field. The other ones teach, and work on refining the results to make them easier to teach, and ultimately, write books. The rest (1%) invent and discover new things.

Comment: @reuns I have no idea how you get the idea that only 1% do actual research, nor how that answers my question.

Comment: I didn't say the rest isn't research. You can see the papers, conferences, publications and books about Fermat last theorem and the modularity theorem to see how all this process organized in less than 10 years.

Answer (score -4):

Usually they have payed staff, some Prof. who are working in this field. So they send your paper to them, they review it. Based on their review it will be published or not. It depends on the quality of the journal, how well they check your work.

Comment: The reviewers are as a rule not actually paid.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. In next hours I should be choose an answer.

Comment: I second Tobias' comment. Reviewers are (1) not staff, and (2) usually* not paid.

*I know of no occurrence of them being paid for journal or conference articles, at least in my field.

Comment: From what I heard they are paid, i guess it depends on the contract or the jornal. Maybe be they are not "paid" in the traditional way. Why would anyone read a 150 pages paper, on a topic no one cares(worst case scenario)? No sorry, only hear say from Prof.. I think it also depends on topic and domain.

Comment: @thetha Do you have anything to back that up, maybe a sample contract from a journal? At leats in my field (computer science), reviewers are simply researchers/professors, *with no stipend, fee, or even contract from the journal which asks them for reviews.*

Comment: @ClementC. This is also the case in math. I have never heard of a reviewer being paid for reviewing papers (except for reviews for MathSciNet which are compensated with some small amount that can be used in the AMS bookstore, but the amount really is tiny).

Comment: @thetha It's a *quid pro quo*. Academics are willing in general to referee papers since they benefit from other academics refereeing their papers.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown then its even worse.

Comment: Even worse? How so?